# Transferring value of javascript variable to asp variable

Tags: javascript, variables, asp-classic, transfer

I've designed a javascript function which returns out an integer value (and before anyone says, no this cannot be done with asp or any server side scripting, at least to my knowledge). And I need the contents of the variable containing the integer value produced to be transferred into an asp variable so that I may do some server side scripting with it. Does anyone have any idea as to how to do this? I'm tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: Do you mean "ASP Classic" (with VB Script) or "ASP.NET WebForms"? (Although it doesn't matter much: the client must *send* the data back  to the server somehow, be it a form postback or otherwise.)

Comment: I'm using ASP Classic

Comment: It cannot be done directly. You might beable to store the javascript value in a hidden form field and then on get/post collect it into an asp variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the preferred method to change server side status (variables) in the browser without reloading the whole page would be to use [AJAX](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=AJAX+introduction).

It's not necessary, but using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you could just call [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
// we are in javascript
var my_value = 42;
$.get("set_my_value.asp?to=" + my_value);
```

By this, you can change some data on the server side (e.g. as Session variable or in a database):

```
' classic ASP page (set_my_value.asp)
dim my_value
my_value = Request.Querystring("to")
Session("MyValue") = my_value
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it directly. You can populate a hidden input in a form with the javascript value. Then on posting the form you can use the value using request("MyHiddenField")

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this via Cookies.

Your javascript function will store value in some Cookie.
In ASP code you reading Cookie.

This cookie could be specific for each user/session, just do not forget to send Cookie name from ASP to JavaScript function.